# Invertible operator

Tags: operator-theory, compact-operators

Let $K:V\to W$ such that $Kf = k$, where $V,W$ are infinite-dimensional Banach spaces. Is it correct to say that in general $f = (K^*K)^{-1}k$, however, when $V=W$, then $f = K^{-1}k$. $T^*$ here denotes the adjoint operator. In other words if $V\ne W$, we can't really talk about $K^{-1}$. I'm just trying to draw a parallel with $K$ being a real-valued matrix.

Answer (score 7):

Inverse operators are a bit more abstract than what one may first think. The notation and ease of defining inverses from linear algebra is misleading. Really, the inverse operator (when it is well-defined) takes $w\in W$ and gives $v\in V$, with the added condition that $Kv = w$. This *is* the definition of the inverse operator. What the operator *looks* like really depends on the context. For example, the inverse operator to a differential operator is a Green's function which you can't nicely represent in terms of the PDE itself in the way you're suggesting. You could, in fact, define an inverse for a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$ if $\dim(W) < \dim(V)$ but you would need to make some specifications on the kinds of output you can have because the system is underdetermined. The way linear algebra is taught at the introductory level is actually a bit detrimental, I think. The notation and somewhat lack of clarity makes functional analysis a lot more difficult than it needs to be.

Comment: Is there a simple explanation for this complication?

Comment: Which complication are you referring to?

Comment: My bad, that the "ease of definning an invers in linear algebra" does not translate into infinite dimension.

Comment: Well on a finite dimensional vector space, a linear map being one-to-one is the same thing as it being onto and hence invertible. This is far from true in infinite dimensions. You can have one-to-one linear maps which are not onto - they can have dense range or not! You can have linear maps which are onto which are not one-to-one. There is also the issue of structure. Bounded (or continuous) linear maps are by far the nicest and even if a linear map is bounded, one-to-one and is onto, its inverse may not be bounded (and largely is not). It can be a bit of a nightmare.

Comment: Ah ill think about that, I disagree on the "even if a linear map is bounded, one-to-one and is onto, its inverse may not be bounded". Dosnt bdd inverse thm give us that the invers is bdd? Or maybe you refer to non-complete spaces?

Comment: Yeah I did. Thanks for catching that.